# How to design an object in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller, oop, class

I can semi-conceptually get this, but I can't wrap my head around the right way to do it.

Specifically, an object that needs to do the following...

```
class Question {
  var $text;
  var $filters = array();
  var $banners = arrya(); //But this has to be within $filter somehow...
  ... //all getter and setter functions
}
```

Now I am going to query a database and get a bunch of data returned, say 4 columns.

```
QuestionText | Filter | Banner | Value
```

I want to end up with an object that looks like....

```
Object
  Questions
   ->Question 1
     ->Text = Question One
     ->Filters
        ->Filter1
           ->Name = Ontario
           Banners
             Banner 1
              ->Name = Male
              ->Value = 20
             Banner 2
              ->Name = Famales
              ->Value = 20
        ->Filter2
           ->Name = Quebec
           Banners
           Banners
             Banner 1
              ->Name = Male
              ->Value = 20
             Banner 2
              ->Name = Famales
              ->Value = 20
   ->Question 2
     ->Text = Question Two
     ->Filters
     ......
     .....
     ....
     ...
```

Because I can only read from the database row by row, I need to find a way to add each new banner and value inside the Question / Filter combination.  Eventually I want to spit it out as a table where each banner is a column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you will need three classes

```
class Question {
   var $text;
   var $filters;
}

class Filter {
   var $name;
   var $banners;
}

class Banner {
   var $name;
   var $value;
}
```

Then you would start off by creating your questions and adding the filters and banners to them like so:

```
$questions = array();
$x = 0;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `questions`");
while ($obj = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    $questions[$x] = new Question();
    $questions[$x]->text = $obj->text;
    $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `filters` WHERE `question` = {$obj->id}");
    $questions[$x]->filters = array();
    $y = 0;
    while ($obj2 = mysql_fetch_object($result2)) {
        $questions[$x]->filters[$y] = new Filter();
        ...
        // and so on
        ...
        $y++;
    }
    $x++;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, really helped make it click. Appreciate you taking the time to lay it out this way, cheers.

Comment: just remember it will produce many database queries and, if not used wisely, may cause horrific performance issues

Comment: I didn't use that part of the code since my data is all in one table.  So I just built the the objects by cycling over each row of data once.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your design will have 3 types of objects:

   - question objects
   - filter objects
   - banner
2. Your data will be stored in 3 different locations

   - question table
   - filter table
   - banner table
3. You have to create a function that will create "Question" objects for you. Let's name it "QuestionFactory". This is what it will do:

   - load row from question table
   - load all related rows from filter table
   - load all related rows from banner table
   - create an object
   - return an object

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't add this into 1 object, but multiple objects.

In this case, you should create a "Banner" class and "Filter" class to your existing "Question" class".

How the output is gonna be, you should not determine this before you start writing it. You should determine what objects you need, what their functionality should be, and what data to store in it.

In this case, in your question object, you should fill the data with a foreach loop (with multiple queries, as you said) and add a new Filter object for each filter you find.

After that, in your filter object, again a foreach loop, adding all banners there, also with objects.

Because your question object now contains filter objects, which on its turn contains banner objects, you can define an output method for these objects. You could possibly figure this out yourself after you have done the above. If not, put a comment here, and I'll help out.